# Keeping track of arguments passed to a function

Tags: python, list, arguments

I have a `for` `loop` passing arguments to a `function`, and I would like to keep track of the history of arguments passed **inside** the function, in order to index them later.

```
def play(arg):

    list = []
    if arg:
        list.append(arg)
```

However, it seems this erases the list at each new argument passed.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of them via a global:

```
lst = []
def play(arg):
    if arg:
        lst.append(arg)
```

Although usually, globals aren't the first place I reach when I want a stateful function... classes are better for this:

```
class PlayTracker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []
    def play(self, arg):
        if arg:
            self.lst.append(arg)
```

To use the class, you need an instance:

```
 pt = PlayTracker()
 pt.play('foo')
 pt.play('bar')
 pt.play('baz')
 print(pt.lst)
```

Comment: You could also define __call__ within the class and use it like play = PlayTracker(); play('foo'); play('bar')

Answer (score 2):

Let's see your code:

```
def play(arg):

    list = [] #The problem is here. This erases the list.
    if arg:
        list.append(arg)
```

Why don't you instantiate your list out of the function and then remove that line from it?

```
list = []

def play(arg):

    if arg:
        list.append(arg)
```

I hope it helps.